# Arami Oved Avi reference to Avraham

Tags: abraham, lavan

Perhaps somebody can help me understand a phrase from this text from the Bechor Shor on  דברים פרק כו פסוק ה:

ארמי אובד אבי: עתה מספר החסדים והצדקות שעשה הקדוש ברוך הוא לאבותינו, ולא ארמי היה אבי אברהם שנולד בארם - נהרים, ואובד היה שיצא מארץ מולדתו, לילך מגוי אל גוי ומממלכה אל עם אחר, שאמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא: "לך לך מארצך וממולדתך", והיה הולך מכאן ולכאן תועה [כדכתיב]: "כאשר התעו אותי", ו"תועה" נקרא אובד, כדכתיב "תעיתי כשה אובד

Why does he say:ולא ארמי היה אבי אברהם שנולד בארם ?  the word ולא is what is confusing me.  I would have thought the phrase should just read:  ארמי היה אבי אברהם שנולד בארם

Any explanation would be apprieciated, and Chag Shavuot Sameach to all.

Comment: The [Rashbam](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%95) this seems to be based on says "אבי אברהם ארמי היה". Maybe ולא here should be read as (or emended to) הלא.

Comment: Shmosel:  Thank you and I agree.  I have also emailed to Responsa to see if perhaps it is a  typo in their text.  Chag Sameach.

Comment: Maybe Bechor Shor is opposing this interpretation of the Rashbam (although it does seem odd that he'd quote it almost in full, if so), as he (the Bechor Shor) interprets the rest of the verse as referring to Yaakov.